# Play Framework 2.2 : Get URL of the requesting page

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.2

PLAY FRAMEWORK JAVA:

I am trying to get the name of the URL that requested the controller function. For example ,
I have a routes as

`GET       /mypage       controllers.Mypage.myfunction()`

and I have another page that requests the same controller

`GET        /anotherpage      controllers.Mypage.myfunction()`

is there a way to find in controllers if the request is from `/mypage` or from `/anotherpage`?

Thanks

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Say you visit `example.com:9000/login?param=test`, then within your controller function:

```
public static Result login() {

    // set to "/login" -- The URI path without query parameters.
    String path = request().path(); 

    // set to "/login?param=test" -- The full URI.
    String uri = request().uri(); 

    // set to "example.com:9000" -- The host name from the request, with port (if specified by the client).
    String host = request().host(); 

    ...
}
```

Comment: is there anyway to figure out the url of view? For example : 

If user lands on www.abc.com/profile, and then hits our controller api, how do I get value of landing url "www.abc.com/profile"?

Comment: @HIRATHAKUR You can use request().host() + request().uri() to build what you want. "uri" also includes any query parameters.

Answer (score 7):

you didn't mention language

In Scala you can get path in controller by

```
val path= request.path
```

or

```
val path=request.uri
```

*i have tried this in play framework 2.2**

---

In Java

```
String path= request.path();
```

or

```
String path=request.url();
```

according to this link   http://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.0.1/api/play/mvc/Http.Request.html

Comment: I am using JAVA.. do you know the same syntax in Java Play framework

Comment: @Inceptor361 did you tried `request.path` or `request.url` in java?

Comment: I get it as `request.headers()` and than check if the string contains `mypage` or `anotherpage`

Comment: yes that's a work around.. if I am running on `http://localhost:9000/login` and then page request comes I get `localhost:9000/login` and I check if string contains `login`

Comment: @Inceptor361 its is limited you have to know already the urls